# No me sale del bucle while

Tags: javascript

No me saca del `while`, le hice una condición que mientras ponga `exit` ya no me ingrese más nombres, pero me sigue pidiendo, ¿Qué puedo hacer?. Adjunto mi código:

```
'use strict'

var nombres = [];
do{
nombres.push(prompt("Ingrese nombre: "));
}while(nombres != "exit");
console.log(nombres);
```

Comment: `nombres` es un array nunca será igual a un `string`

Answer (score 5):

`nombres` es un `array` nunca será igual a un `string`, tienes que crear otra variable, por ejemplo `nombre` (en singular) la cual usas para evaluar, y está variable la ingresas en el array

```js
var nombres = [];
let nombre="";
do{
  nombre = prompt("Ingrese nombre: ");
  if(nombre !="exit")
  {
    nombres.push(nombre);
  }
}while(nombre != "exit");
console.log(nombres);
```

Otra forma es haber puesto si lo incluye usando la función [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var nombres = [];
do{
  nombres.push(prompt("Ingrese nombre: "));
}while(!nombres.includes("exit"));
console.log(nombres);
```

Pero de esta última manera estas obligado a ingresar "exit" en el array, y quizás eso no lo requieras, ya que exit vendría a ser un comando no un nombre

Comment: Muchas gracias ya pude solucionar gracias a este espacio, mil gracias

Answer (score 2):

Lo que estás haciendo en la condición del while es comparar un array con una cadena. En lugar de inicializar `nombres` como un array, puedes inicializarlo como un string.

De esta forma estamos diciendo al while que el bucle se va a repetir mientras el valor ingresado en el `prompt` sea distinto a `exit`, ejemplo:

```js
var nombres = ""; // inicializo a nombres como una cadena.

do {
  nombres = prompt("Ingrese nombre: "); // guardo el valor del prompt en la variable.
} while(nombres != "exit"); // mientras el texto ingresado en el prompt sea distinto a exit, el bucle del while se repite.

console.log(nombres);
```